# Getting the GCC include path with GNU Autotools

Tags: c, linux, autotools

I'm writing an implementation of the C preprocessor that, when running on Linux, needs to know the path on which to find header files. This can be obtained by running `gcc -v`. I want to compile the results into the binary of my preprocessor rather than having to invoke `gcc -v` on every run, so I'm currently thinking of writing a Python script to be run at compile time, that would obtain the path and write it into a small C source file to be included in the build.

On the other hand, I get the impression GNU Autotools is basically the specialist in obtaining system-specific information to be used at build time. Does Autotools have the ability to obtain the `#include` path in such a way that it can be incorporated as a string into the program being built (as opposed to being used for the build process)? If so, how?

Comment: Why do you have your own (external) preprocessor? What for? Current GCC have *internal* preprocessing... Did you consider instead customizing GCC, e.g. with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) and work on internal GCC representations? Some preprocessor symbols are builtin inside GCC (i.e. its `cc1`)

Comment: Apparently you are coding a compiler for your [aklo](https://github.com/russellw/aklo) language. You could have mentioned that in your question...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Well it seemed sufficient context for making the question clear, to note that I'm implementing a C preprocessor, but yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up parsing gcc's include path with a Python script:

```
print 'string gcc_include_path[] = {'
for s in sys.stdin:
    if s[0] == ' ':
        s = s.strip()
        print '\t"'+s+'",'
print '};'
```

and calling it from Makefile:

```
echo | cpp -Wp,-v 2>&1 >/dev/null | python include_path.py >include_path
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the internal `include/` directory used by GCC, run the `gcc -print-file-name=include` command, e.g. in shell syntax

```
the_gcc_include_dir=$(gcc -print-file-name=include)
```

This `$the_gcc_include_dir`directory contains files like `<stdarg.h>` and `<stddef.h>` and many others.

You also want the `include-fixed/` directory, so

```
the_gcc_include_fixed_dir=$(gcc -print-file-name=include-fixed)
```

This `$the_gcc_include_fixed_dir` contains files like `<limits.h>` and also a useful `README`

<sup>You probably don't need *autotools* in your case.</sup>

Comment: Not really. Just running `gcc -v` gives configuration information about that GCC.